# Проблемы при вставке кириллицы через sqlplus

Tags: кодировка, oracle

Всем доброе время суток.

Задача: необходимо с помощью скрипта заполнить значениями таблицу.
Проблема: из-за проблем с кодировкой в sqlplus значения вставляются непонятно по какому алгоритму.
Пример:
Таблица

```
CREATE TABLE WORDS(article VARCHAR2(100));
```

Текст скрипта.

```
INSERT INTO WORDS(article) VALUES ('Перчик');
INSERT INTO WORDS(article) VALUES ('Перчик ');
INSERT INTO WORDS(article) VALUES (' Перчик');
INSERT INTO WORDS(article) VALUES (' Перчик ');
INSERT INTO WORDS(article) VALUES ('Перец');
INSERT INTO WORDS(article) VALUES ('Перец ');
INSERT INTO WORDS(article) VALUES (' Перец');
INSERT INTO WORDS(article) VALUES (' Перец ');
INSERT INTO WORDS(article) VALUES ('Греция');
INSERT INTO WORDS(article) VALUES ('Греция ');
INSERT INTO WORDS(article) VALUES ('Оливки');
INSERT INTO WORDS(article) VALUES ('Оливки ');
INSERT INTO WORDS(article) VALUES ('Проблемы');
INSERT INTO WORDS(article) VALUES ('Проблемы ');
commit;
exit;
```

Запускаю скрипт

```
G:\scripts>sqlplus login/passwd@bd @test_script.sql
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Sun Feb 21 21:42:28 2016
Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
1 row created.
1 row created.
1 row created.
1 row created.
ERROR:
ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated
1 row created.
ERROR:
ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated
1 row created.
1 row created.
1 row created.
ERROR:
ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated
ERROR:
ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated
1 row created.
1 row created.
Commit complete.
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit
 Production
G:\scripts>
```

При этом через pl/sql developer все значения хорошо вставляются.
Параметры в БД: `NLS_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN,NLS_TERRITORY=AMERICA, NLS_CHARACTERSET=AL32UTF8`
В переменных окружения прописано `NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8`

Пытался: добавлять в скрипт(в батнике) принудительно NLS_LANG и chcp

```
set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8
set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251
chcp 1251
chcp 866
chcp 65001
```

Ничего не помогает. Прошу помочь с этой магией.

Comment: и какая проблема?

Comment: @Jean-Claude Необходимо таблицу заполнить значениями, таблица заполняется не полностью. В этом проблема. Необходимо решение, с помощью которого можно будет всегда через SQLPlus вставлять кириллицу.

Comment: И нужно объяснение, почему такая проблема вообще происходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Справился.
Проблема была в том, что в IDE Intellij IDEA, в которой создавались и редактировались файлы, кодировка файлов была windows-1251 (а не UTF-8)